# How to know if a set of threads has finished

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I want to know if various threads has finished doing their work and then raise an event, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub xTask(ByVal Value As String)
    Try
        Dim th As Thread

        For i As Integer = 1 To 254
            th = New Thread(Sub() YTask(Value + i))
            th.IsBackground = True
            th.Start()
        Next

        'If all threads have finished working, raise an event

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm completely new at threading, I'm almost sure that this isn't the best way to do it, could anyone give me some suggestions please?

I'm using Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very unclear to me what you are really trying to accomplish, so it's hard to recommend a best practice.

But for what you are asking, doing a `thread.Join()` on every thread that you start will ensure that you wait for all threads to complete.

See .NET 2.0 doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.80).aspx

Your code would then look something like this:

```
Private Sub xTask(ByVal value As String)
    Dim threadList As List(Of Thread) = New List(Of Thread)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 254
        Dim t = New Thread(Sub() YTask(value))
        t.IsBackground = True ' not sure why you want this if you are going to wait for the thread to finish anyways.
        t.Start()
        threadList.Add(t)
    Next

    ' wait for all threads to finish.
    ' The loop will only exit once all threads have completed their work.
    For Each t In threadList
        t.Join()
    Next

    ' Raise event now that all the threads have completed.
End Sub
```

**EDIT: Making the number of threads adjustable**

Usually, starting an excessive amount of threads to perform some work is not the best idea.  Also depending on how resource intensive each of the thread's work is, it can cause an overall slowdown of your program.

Usually, you want to test which number of threads will give you the proper balance between accomplishing the work faster and in parallel vs. abusing system resources and causing overall performance degradation.

The following code should allow you to easily tune the number of threads to perform your work, and find the right balance for you.

```
Sub Main()
    xTask("192.168.10.")
End Sub

Private Sub xTask(ByVal value As String)
    Dim ipAddressesToScan As Queue(Of String) = New Queue(Of String)

    SyncLock ipAddressesToScan ' I'm not 100% sure this locking is needed here, but I would do it to be safe, and it doesn't hurt.
        For i As Integer = 1 To 254
            ipAddressesToScan.Enqueue(value & i)
        Next
    End SyncLock

    Dim threadList As List(Of Thread) = New List(Of Thread)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10 ' <-- change this to whatever number of threads seems to work best for you.
        Dim t = New Thread(Sub() YTask(ipAddressesToScan))
        't.IsBackground = True ' don't think you need this TBH.
        t.Start()
        threadList.Add(t)
    Next

    ' Wait for all threads to finish processing the queue.
    For Each t In threadList
        t.Join()
    Next

    ' Raise event HERE to signal that all the threads have completed.
    Console.WriteLine("All threads have finished their work")
End Sub

Private Sub YTask(ByVal ipAddressesToScan As Queue(Of String))
    Dim ipAddress As String
    Do
        SyncLock ipAddressesToScan
            If ipAddressesToScan.Count = 0 Then
                ipAddress = Nothing
            Else
                ipAddress = ipAddressesToScan.Dequeue
            End If
        End SyncLock

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress) Then
            ' Perform your scan here...
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId & " is scanning IP Address " & ipAddress)
        End If
    Loop While Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)
End Sub
```

Comment: Look, I'm trying to scan for the IP's that are connected to an application. "xTask" is being executed on a thread called from a main window, when all the threads executed on "xTask" have finished their work I want to raise an event from "xTask" that the main window will catch.

Comment: Well, as long as `xTask` is ***not*** executing on the UI thread (the main window), then even though the above may not be the absolute best way to do it, it is simple enough and should certainly work fine.  Just give it a try.  However, if `xTask` is running on the UI thread, your app may appear to freeze while it blocks waiting for the threads to complete their work. (TBH, I'm not even sure if running the above on the UI thread will actually be a problem, because `t.Join()` is suposed to keep pumping messages while it waits.  Again, try it out, and see if it works for you!)

Comment: xTask isn't running on the UI thread, I tried using t.Join and the app becomes very slow while executing the threads.

Comment: Well, you are trying to execute 250+ threads at the same time.  It's kind of normal unless you have 250+ CPU cores.  Perhaps you should consider performing your work with less threads.  If you are interested in solutions to do that, perhaps a separate question is a good idea.

Comment: btw, I wouldn't mind trying to expand the answer to make it work with an adjustable number of threads so that you can find which number is right for you.  However, I would have to better understand what `YTask(value)` does.  I was expecting that each thread would get passed a different value.  But the fact that they all get the same `value` is a bit confusing to me.  If you can clear that up for me, I may be able to provide you something more efficient.  Ideally, add the information to your original post by editing it. Good luck!

Comment: Oh sorry, the value I pass is "value + i" where value is "192.168.10." for example , and "i" is supposed to be each host on the network. "YTask" tries to connect to each host and if it succeed then it raises an event.

Comment: @ozatarain: Updated my answer. I hope it helps you tune your app. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @sstan I've implemented the code on the app and it worked fine.

Comment: I created a Public (global) threadlist, and fired a thread in an instantiated class, added the thread to the the threadlist, i.e., `ThreadList.Add(t)`, but when the code sits in the loop waiting for the thread to complete, the thread stops.  Is there a way to have threads complete while the loop is going?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Task library for this (assuming you are using .Net 4 upwards).

Add each new task to a list and you can wait for all to finish in one line as shown below:

```
Private Sub xTask(ByVal Value As String)
    Try
        Dim task As Task
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)

        For i As Integer = 1 To 254
            task = New Task(Sub() YTask(Value))
            tasks.Add(task)
            task.Start()
        Next

        ' wait up to 5 seconds for all tasks to complete
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray, 5000)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you meant to use [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) here. On completion of the background worker processing (or if it's cancelled) you can raise `RunWorkerCompleted` event.